# Extract result of sql request in a rest webservice

Tags: sql, web-services, rest, jdbc, jersey

I am using this code to create a login webservice to database

```
public class classeConnection {
@GET
@Path (value="log/{a}/{b}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String execMAJ(@PathParam("a")String name,@PathParam("b")String lastname )throws SQLException  {
      String req;
      try  {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e ){};
      Connection  cn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codezone4", "root","");
      Statement st=cn.createStatement();
      req="select id from utilisateur where nom = '+name+' and prenom = '+lastname+' ";
      st.close(); 
      cn.close();
      System.out.println("success");
      return "login";
}
}
```

My code is working but I don't know how to extract the result of the sql request ( here id ) 
Are there any suggestions to this issue? Please help!

Comment: I need help !! Any one to answer :(

Comment: Your code isn't executing the query at all. I'd suggest you invest some time in learning the JDBC basics (eg via [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)). Also note that your current query doesn't use the values of `name` and `lastname`, but if it would in its current way it would be susceptible to SQL injection. Please read up on `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I added this line to call the request "boolean boo= st.execute(req);" it returns true

Comment: That isn't in your question, and even then if you'd take the time to look at the API and the tutorial, then you'd know that `executeQuery` is what you need to use if you want to get results.

Comment: my bad !! I deleted this line at first by mistake !

Comment: But using this line I am getting only a boolean variable not the results

Comment: `execute` is not the same thing as `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class classeConnection {

  @GET
  @Path (value="log/{a}/{b}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String execMAJ(@PathParam("a")String name,@PathParam("b")String lastname )throws SQLException  {

  String req;
  try  {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e ){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try { 
      Connection  cn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codezone4", "root","");
      Statement st=cn.createStatement();
      req="select id from utilisateur where nom = "+name+" and prenom = "+lastname+" LIMIT 1";
      ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(req);
      if(res.first()) {
        String id = res.getString("id");
        System.out.println("id = "+id);
      } else {
        System.out.println("not found foo!");
      }
  }
  catch (SQLException s){
      s.printStackTrace();
  }  
  catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
    st.close();
    cn.close();
  }
  return "login";
  }

}
```